# Resizing a jqGrid when window resizes using UI.Layout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I'm trying to get my jqGrid to resize automatically when the window is resized.  And I'm using jQuery UI.layout.  I've looked at the following links:
[make-jqgrid-fill-its-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919723/make-jqgrid-fill-its-container) and [resize-jqgrid-when-browser-is-resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875225/resize-jqgrid-when-browser-is-resized).  But no matter what I do, the grid won't resize.  If the width of the grid is 900, and I force it to 600, it stays at 900.  It's like the request to change the width is just being ignored.  I have autowidth: true and I've played around with forceFit and shrinkToFit values.  But nothing is working.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Update:
It seems like the code used to reference the grid:

```
  var gridId = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#' + gridId).setGridWidth(paneState.innerWidth - 2);
```

wasn't actually getting the grid.  In the jqGrid src, this.grid was always undefined.  When I passed in the actual name of my grid, list, it worked.  Now I just need to get the correct name that the function wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the width of the jqGrid, I'm using the following line of code without issue:

```
$('#myGrid').jqGrid('setGridWidth', newWidth);
```

`myGrid` corresponds to the id of the HTML table that is used by jqGrid.

Comment: The problem was with the way the function in the example code was referencing the grid id.  Using $("#list").setGridWidth() also worked.