# Make jqGrid fill parent without losing its horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: jqgrid, scrollbar

How can I get my (first) jqGrid to fill its parent container **without** losing its horizontal scrollbar by putting it too far down? (The scrollbar being the one created by the `scroll: 1` option, e.g., "virtual scrolling".) It seems to use the height I give it *without* allowing for the scrollbar, and so the scrollbar ends up past the bottom of the area I'm trying to keep it in. I've seen these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919723/make-jqgrid-fill-its-container) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875225/resize-jqgrid-when-browser-is-resized) about resizing the grid (and their answers), but while useful (they got me this far), they don't address the scrollbar problem.

The page's layout looks like this (it's not mine; I *might* be able to get it changed, but it would best if I could avoid that — with the exception that I can do just about anything I want with `gridWrapper`):

HTML:

```html
<body>
  <div id="pageHeader">Header section</div>
  <div id="pageBody">
    <div id="gridWrapper" style="height: 100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pageFooter">Footer section</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}
#pageHeader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 99px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}
#pageBody {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 45px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#pageFooter {
  background-color: #eee;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0; 
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 44px;
  border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

My grid creation/sizing code looks like this (you can tell it's testing/prototyping code):

```js
function createGrid(data) {
  var colNames, colModel, index, grid, gridParent, theFudge, heightFudge = 0;

  colNames = [
    "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five",
    "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten",
    "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "teen", "Fifteen",
    "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eightteen", "Nineteen", "Twenty",
    "Twenty One", "Twenty Two", "Twenty Three", "Twenty Four",
    "Twenty Five"
  ];
  colModel = [];
  for (index = 0; index < colNames.length; ++index) {
    colModel.push({
      name:   "col" + index,
      id:     "col" + index,
      width:  75
    });
  }

  gridParent = $("#gridWrapper");
  grid = $('<table id="theTable"></table>').appendTo(gridParent);
  grid.jqGrid({
    datatype:    'local',
    data:        data,
    height:      gridParent.height() - heightFudge,
    width:       gridParent.width(),
    shrinkToFit: false,
    colNames:    colNames,
    colModel:    colModel,
    rownumbers:  true,
    rownumWidth: 75,
    scroll:      1
  });

  $(window).resize(resizeGrid);

  function resizeGrid() {
    grid.jqGrid('setGridWidth', gridParent.width());
    grid.jqGrid('setGridHeight', gridParent.height() - heightFudge);
    grid.trigger('reloadGrid');
  }
}
```

You see that `heightFudge` value (which in the above is just `0`). If I don't fudge the height, the scrollbar is beyond the bottom of `pageBody`, intruding on (and being hidden by) `pageFooter`. On my browser with my fonts and my window decorations etc., etc., etc., the fudge factor (height of the scrollbar) is 24 pixels. But of course that will vary.

How can I get the grid to fill the grid wrapper and keep its horizontal scrollbar within the height I give it? (Or how can I reliably determine the fudge factor at runtime, but that seems kludgy to me.)

[Here's a live copy of the above](http://jsbin.com/oworex) ([source link](http://jsbin.com/oworex/edit#javascript,html)), with data for the table and controls for experimenting with the fudge and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `height` parameter of jqGrid can be used to specify the height of *inner* part of grid (the height of the body). It seems to me that you can fix the problem by modifying of `resizeGrid` to about the following

```js
function resizeGrid() {
  var $grid = $("#theTable"),
      $gbox = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid"), // or $("gbox_theTable");
      outerHeight = $gbox.height() - $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'height');
  $grid.jqGrid('setGridWidth', gridParent.width());
  $grid.jqGrid('setGridHeight', gridParent.height() - heightFudge - outerHeight);
  $grid.trigger('reloadGrid');
}
```

You have to call `resizeGrid` to fix its height immediately after the grid is created. You can see the fixed demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/T.J.Crowder.htm).

Comment: Of course, I should have thought of measuring the resulting element after-the-fact (I did think of it later, when dealing with allowing column headers to be as tall as needed; but was going about it a more awkward way than yours). Many thanks!! JSBin update here: [live](http://jsbin.com/oworex/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/oworex/2/edit).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: You are welcome! I agree that `outerHeight` which I used can be wrong interpreted.

Comment: And actually, I only need to do it once, not on every resize. But again, the concept was spot-on (and probably solves a second problem for me). Further update: [live](http://jsbin.com/oworex/3) | [source](http://jsbin.com/oworex/3/edit)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: You are right in the most cases, but if you would call some methods of jqGrid which change the "outer" part of grid you have to recalculate the `heightFudge` value. For example with respect of `filterToolbar`, which I would recommend you, you can include filter toolbar in the grid. With respect of [setGroupHeaders](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:groupingheadar) you can insert grouping headers. Moreover in some scenarios one uses wrapping column headers (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7256972/315935)) and the user can resize the column size.