# in jqGrid the grid size should be based on form or window size

Tags: jqgrid

I wanna grid in jqGrid should vary its size dynamically depending on the window or browser size. Is there any way to achieve the same. Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define `autowidth:true` option of jqGrid.

If you want have the grid width changed after the user resize the browser window you should call `setGridWidth` on every `resize` event (see [Resize jqGrid when browser is resized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875225/resize-jqgrid-when-browser-is-resized))