# jqGrid: pager add after body

Tags: jqgrid, pager

I want to add the pager of the jqGrid on a different place then after the body of the jqGid. But the div is always set after the body of the jqGrid...

I want it like:

```
<div id='header'>Header</div>
<div id='scroller'>
    <div><table>jqGrid body</table></div>
</div>
<div id='pager'>pager</div>
```

But jqGid always put the pager div like:

```
<div id='header'>Header</div>
    <div id='scroller'>
        <div><table>jqGrid body</table></div>
        <div id='pager'>pager</div>
    </div>
```

Is there a solution to put the pager div where you like in the page??

I want this because i have a many columns. When a put the option:
autowidth: true is will show a scrollbar, that's correct. 
But when the user resize the browser i want that the following:

1. Table hold the current size.
2. The div who contains the table wil resize and show a scrollbar.
3. Header and footer will resize(they are always visible and they are not a part of the 
   scroll div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct you should just use `shrinkToFit:false` setting of jqGrid. You can optionally combine it with `autowidth:true` or set `width` parameter of jqGrid and change it if the browser windows will be resized (call `setGridWidth` on every `resize` event see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875225/resize-jqgrid-when-browser-is-resized) for details).

Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridScrolled.htm) and [another one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridScrolledResizable.htm) which has the horizontal scroll bar only on the grid body and not on the pager or header.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! That helped me out! I used:  $("#jqGrid").setGridWidth($(window).width()) and that did the trick!