# jqGrid Resizing Problem

Tags: html, css, jqgrid, resize

I have a jqGrid at my web page. I have a resizing problem. When I restore down my web page, all the elements at my page resizes automatically however my jqGrid table doesn't. Actually I have edited my table's width as follows:

```
...
width:1000,
...
```

I want it has a minimum width but have a automatic resizing when I restore down (get more smaller) my web page.

How can I do that?

**EDIT:**

I tried thatbut I am not sure is this the right way:
`confTable` is my jqGrid id and `content` is the parent element's id of it.

```
$("#confTable").jqGrid('gridResize', { minWidth: 800, minHeight: 100 });
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
                var gridWidth = $("#confTable").width();
                var contentWidth = $("#content").width();                    
                if (gridWidth > 0 &&                      
                        Math.abs(gridWidth - contentWidth) > 5) {
                    $("#confTable").jqGrid('setGridWidth', contentWidth);
                }

 }).trigger('resize');
```

I wanted to implement the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875225/resize-jqgrid-when-browser-is-resized) described. However setgridWidht and the lines of .attr() didn't work. Is my code browser compatible and what is the wrong can be while I was trying the implement the solution of that question?

**PS:**

It says: $("#confTable").setGridWidth is not a function. Actually I need to resize my jqGrid according to its parent's parent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example you could try:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $("#confTable").setGridWidth($(this).width() * .95);        
});
```

Comment: It says: `$("#confTable").setGridWidth is not a function` and what this refers there? Actually I need to resize my jqGrid according to its parent's parent.

Comment: this would refer to the window object there. i just chose that as a test example. are you using the latest verion of jqGrid? my example works for me using the latest.