# resize jqgrid when parent div changes with an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a dashboard with several jqgrids. My dashboard windows can individually expand to fill up the page while all other windows disapear. There is also a toggle to shrink back

If i have a jqgrid, in that window, when it expands I would like the grid width to expand and shrink a as well.

Is there some way to bind the grid to its parent div so it can expand and shrink?

Sample so far which does not work.

```
$('.portlet-content').bind('resize', function() {
        jQuery("#gridConfirm").setGridWidth($('.portlet-content').width()-5, true);
    }).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: Do you tried the way from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875225/resize-jqgrid-when-browser-is-resized)?

Comment: I actually use that code elsewhere, however it does not work for divs. At least it has not worked for me.

Comment: You should just get `$('#parentDiv').width()` inside of the `resize` event handler.

Comment: Right that i can do, but i dont know how to build the resize event handler. I've added what i have.

Answer (score 1):

You should bind [jQuery.resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) to the `window` object. Try this one

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#gridConfirm").jqGrid('setGridWidth', $('.portlet-content').width()-5, true);
}).trigger('resize');
```