# Responsive jqGrid with bootstrap classes to the column headers

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

I have the below simple jQGrid. All I need is responsive table with some columns hidden in mobile view using bootstrap helper classes such as hidden-xs

```
 var gridInfoJSON = JSON.parse($('#hdn-categorysummary').val());

   var catGrid= jQuery("#categorysummary").jqGrid({
        url: '/Category/GetCategories/',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',

        colNames: ["Id", "Active", "Name", "Duration"],
        colModel: [
        { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', hidden: true },
        { name: 'IsActive', index: 'IsActive', align: 'center', formatter: activeCheckBoxFormatter, sortable: false,classes:'col-sm-1' },
        { name: 'CategoryName', index: 'CategoryName', formatter: generateCategoryNameLink, sortable: false },

        { name: 'ComboDuration', index: 'ComboDuration', classes:'hidden-xs' , align: 'center', sortable: false }       
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            id: 'Id',
            repeatitems: false
        },

        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        rownumbers: true,
        rowNum: 1000,
        sortname: 'Id',
        caption: 'BookingCategories',
        loadComplete: function () {
            var table = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                updatePagerIcons(table);
                var targetWidth = $(".page-content").width() - 20;
                $('#categorysummary').jqGrid('setGridWidth', targetWidth);
                $('#categorysummary').parents('div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv:first').width(targetWidth + 1);
            }, 0);
        },
        gridComplete:function(){
          applyClassesToHeaders(catGrid);
        },
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true
```

The column ComboDuration I want to hide for mobile devices. So I tried the following code that called from gridComplete event.

```
var applyClassesToHeaders = function (grid) {
    var trHead = jQuery("thead:first tr", grid.hdiv);
    var colModel = grid.getGridParam("colModel");    
    for (var iCol = 0; iCol < colModel.length; iCol++) {
        var columnInfo = colModel[iCol];
        if (columnInfo.classes) {
            var headDiv = jQuery("th:eq(" + iCol + ")", trHead);            
            headDiv.addClass(columnInfo.classes);
        }
    }
};
```

It successfully adds the classes to the header, but unfortunately jgGrid generates a code like below

`<th class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr hidden-xs" role="columnheader" id="categorysummary_ComboDuration" style="width: 122px;">` Look at the style width:122px. How to get rid of this?

**[DEMO LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/glYfyqGoB3k8KTd4CVkk?p=preview)**

Comment: Could you add some test data to the question? In the case one will have full demo and I will try modify it. It's important to know **which fork of jqGrid and in which version you use?**

Comment: @Oleg, Sure. I am working on fiddle. I used ` jqGrid  4.6.0`

Comment: @Oleg, Somehow made it to hide. But still it is not looking good. Check the [fiddle link](http://plnkr.co/edit/glYfyqGoB3k8KTd4CVkk?p=preview) and preview in full window in chrome and resize to mobile view

Comment: @Oleg, seems like `jqgfirstrow` sets the width and gives the blank space for the cells as well

Comment: I'm back now. Yes the reason is the requirement to apply `'hidden-xs'` calsses to the corresponding column of `jqgfirstrow`, the corresponding `<th>` of the header (like you do inside of `applyClassesToHeaders`). The same class needed be set to the column of filterToolbar too, if you use it of cause. I will look in your demo and write later my answer.

Comment: I have to go away for some time, but the code could be something like http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/. I will write my answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to remove inline CSS style `width` you can use call like `.css("width", "");`, but I don't think that it's the problem which you have. I think that what you really need to do is to apply the class `hidden-xs` on the corresponding cell of the first row (`tr.jqgfirstrow`) of the grid and on the corresponding cells of every row of the column header. The function `applyClassesToHeaders` can be changed to the following:

```js
function applyClassesToHeaders(table) {
    var columnInfo, iCol, iRow,
        htable = $(table.grid.hDiv).find("table.ui-jqgrid-htable")[0],
        firstRow = table.rows[0];
        colModel = $(table).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");     
    for (iCol = 0; iCol < colModel.length; iCol++) {
        columnInfo = colModel[iCol];
        if (columnInfo.classes) {
            for (iRow = 0; iRow < htable.rows.length; iRow++) {
                $(htable.rows[iRow].cells[iCol]).addClass(columnInfo.classes);
            }
            $(firstRow.cells[iCol]).addClass(columnInfo.classes);
        }
    }
}

applyClassesToHeaders($grid[0]);
```

You can see the results on the modified demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/2/

By the way, the same code works even if you use `filterToolbar`: see http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/3/

The last remark. The above demos looks correctly, but jqGrid still work not full correctly in `setGridWidth` function. It "sees" not the hidden column because of the applied class as hidden. It take in consideration only the value of `hidden` property of `colModel`. So if you will find some problems in another more complex example you will have to add setting of `hidden` property (or the call of `hideCol` method). I will analyse the problem more and add the corresponding changes in free jqGrid code, but if you have to use jqGrid 4.6 than you have to follows described above steps.

**UPDATED:** I made the corresponding changes in the code of jqGrid in the fork ["free jqGrid"](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop since the end of 2014, short after changing the Licence agreements of jqGrid and starting [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). Free jqGrid have the property `labelClasses` together with `classes`. Thus to solve the problem which you describe one don't need to call any `applyClassesToHeaders` method. It's enough just add `classes: "hidden-xs", labelClasses: "hidden-xs"` properties to the corresponding columns of the grid. See the corresponding JSFiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/5/. I will publish today version 4.9 of free jqGrid. So the latest changes will be included in the release.

**UPDATED 2:** The demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/6/ is the same as the previous one, but it uses just released free jqGrid 4.9 from CDN jsDelivr.com.

Comment: This is excellent. I put them in my application and make it work. I will get back to you in case if I find any other problem. You saved a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan: See **UPDATED** part of my answer

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for! Thanks Oleg!