# jqGrid use rest of page

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid, and have it set up like this:

```
<body>
   <div>
      Header
   </div>
   <div>
      <table id="list4"></table>
   </div>
</body>
```

I am populating it using the demo code from here: http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html, Loading Data-> Array Data.

I want the grid to take up the rest of the bottom of the page, and, grow / shrink as the page is resized.  In addition, I would like scrollbars when the grid goes off the edge of the screen.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You can have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875225/resize-jqgrid-when-browser-is-resized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach a `resize` event to the window like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $("#list4").setGridHeight(<some calculation>);
});
```

See the documentation of `setGridHeight` here:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#grid_related_methods

Be careful with using `resize` events though since they are triggered differently by different browsers. See here:

http://api.jquery.com/resize/