# responsive/fluid jQGrid with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

I started creating application uses jQgrid in many places. Now the customer wanted to use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) so they can view the site nicely in iPad.

We have atmost done everything, except jQGrid plugin. It uses a `px width` for defining width of the grid and `column width`.

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
    url:'server.php?q=2',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:55},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90},
        {name:'name',index:'name asc, invdate', width:100},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right"},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right"},      
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right"},       
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
    ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pager2',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"JSON Example"
});
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

I have no idea about How to deal this responsive issue with jQGrid. Alternatively I can replace jQGrid with [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) Plugin for responsiveness. But we use jQgrid in many place and functions very well, we dont want to break existing functionality.

Any idea/suggestions to use jQgrid as responsiveness/fluid layout support?

Answer (score 9):

I found this solution, it works fine on my apps.

Wrap you table in a div :

```
<div id="jqGrid_container">
    <table id="jqList"></table>
    <div id="jqPager"></div>
</div>
```

And in your javascript code :

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    var width = $('#jqGrid_container').width();
    $('#jqList').setGridWidth(width);
});
```

or if you don't need to resize, just :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var width = $('#jqGrid_container').width();
    $('#jqList').setGridWidth(width);
});
```

I think you also need to put in your jqgrid options : 
                autowidth: true,
                shrinkToFit: true,

Answer (score 5):

I suggest looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875225/resize-jqgrid-when-browser-is-resized) for some ideas on how to make the grid fluid using the `setGridWidth` method. In addition you should look the following grid [options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options):

> - **autowidth**
>
> When set to true, the grid width is recalculated automatically to the width of the parent element. This is done only initially when the grid is created. In order to resize the grid when the parent element changes width you should apply custom code and use the setGridWidth method for this purpose
>
> - **shrinkToFit**
>
> This option, if set, defines how the the width of the columns of the grid should be re-calculated, taking into consideration the width of the grid. If this value is true, and the width of the columns is also set, then every column is scaled in proportion to its width.

The `shrinkToFit` option is set by default, but you will need to explicitly set `autowidth`.

Does that help?

Comment: How about this template with jQGrid plugin? https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/ace-responsive-admin-template-WB0B30DGR

Answer (score 3):

You can add this piece of code :

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
......
 beforeRequest: function() {
                    responsive_jqgrid($("#divWhereYourgridIsDisplayed"));
                },
.......
});
```

And after this, you should add:

```
 function responsive_jqgrid(jqgrid) {
                jqgrid.find('.ui-jqgrid').addClass('clear-margin span12').css('width', '');
                jqgrid.find('.ui-jqgrid-view').addClass('clear-margin span12').css('width', '');
                jqgrid.find('.ui-jqgrid-view > div').eq(1).addClass('clear-margin span12').css('width', '').css('min-height', '0');
                jqgrid.find('.ui-jqgrid-view > div').eq(2).addClass('clear-margin span12').css('width', '').css('min-height', '0');
                jqgrid.find('.ui-jqgrid-sdiv').addClass('clear-margin span12').css('width', '');
                jqgrid.find('.ui-jqgrid-pager').addClass('clear-margin span12').css('width', '');
            }
```

Hope this works :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make it responsive with a very simple method.

Just open your CSS and give width in **%** .

Example:

```
ui-grid{ width:100% !important; }
```

Then change table body accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This works well for bootstrap responsive

```
jQuery("#your-list-id").setGridWidth($('.your-reference-element').width()-10, true);
```

will use "your-reference-element" width to resize the grid

Answer (score 0):

Customised CSS

I tried the following code but observed that it did not provide any scroller for responsive devices. Hence decided to customise the JQGRID stylesheet:

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    var $grid = $("#list"),
        newWidth = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().width();
    $grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidth, true);
});
```

Please find my hack for making JQ Grid properly responsive

/**** JQ grid responsiveness ***/

```
#gview_jqgrid, div#myPager {width:100% !important;height:100% !important;}
.ui-jqgrid-hdiv, .ui-jqgrid-htable {width:100% !important;height:100% !important;}
.ui-jqgrid-bdiv, #jqgrid {width:100% !important;height:100% !important;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hbox {padding-right:0 !important;}
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td { white-space: pre-wrap !important;}
div#gbox_jqgrid { width: 100% !important; overflow-x: scroll; margin-bottom: 80px !important;}
```

Add this to the custom stylesheet & get set to view the JQGrid fully responsive!

Any other suggestions will be most welcomed. Try it out & Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Next code makes all jqgrid tables on page responsive:

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
    $('.ui-jqgrid').each(function(){
        $('#'+$(this).attr("id").substring(5)).setGridWidth($(this).parent().width());
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

New version of jqGrid 5.0 has native support of Bootstrap.

> As of version 5.0 Guriddo jqGrid can be adapted easy with any CSS framework. We have developed a Bootstrap port. To use the feature you will need only to include the appropriate CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="path_to_css_files/ui.jqgrid-bootstrap.css" />
```

file and tell jqGrid to use Bootstrap – with the option:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid( {
    ...
    styleUI : "Bootstrap",
    ...
 });
```

> Except Column Chooser and re sizing the grid with a mouse we support all the jqGrid existing features.

[**Demo**](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/bootstrap/)

[**Source**](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1484)