# Can JqGrid made responsive to display on mobile devices?

Tags: jqgrid

Can JqGrid become responsive to display on mobile devices.

I have gone through below link, but not sure whether resize events would fire on mobile devices.

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
$("#jqgrid").setGridWidth($(window).width());
}).trigger('resize'); -- Resize event will trigger on mobile devices?
```

[Resize jqGrid when browser is resized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875225/resize-jqgrid-when-browser-is-resized)

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the width parameter from your colModel.This piece of code may help you.

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    $("#jqgrid").setGridWidth($('#form-box').width() - 30, true);
}).trigger('resize');
```

And change your html like,

```
<div id="form-box">
     <table id="jqgrid">
     </table>
     <div id="pager"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can make it responsive :**

```
 *its very simple method,*
```

just open your Css and give width in % .

Like

```
ui-grid{ width:100% !important; }
```

then change table body accordingly......